# Camry LE 1994 trunk lock not working

Tags: toyota, locks, camry

I locked the trunk of my Toyota Camry LE 1994 4 Cyl. Now when I insert the key to unlock it, it doesn't rotate. What can I do now? What will be the cost to fix it?

Note: The keyhole is horizontal although I think it should stay vertical while locked.

Comment: This may seem obvious but is there a remote release near the drivers seat?

Comment: Yes, when I release the lid doesn't go up.

Answer (score 1):

To open the trunk with the least amount of damage you need to gain access to the latch. This will require taking out the back seat or if you are lucky just folding it down. Once access to the trunk has been achieved you need to activate the latch. Some vehicles have a marked "Emergency Trunk Release" lever. Lacking that you will have to unbolt the latch from the the body or the trunk lid panel.

Comment: I can fold the sit down and enter into the trunk with a torch. But I am not sure where is the latch.

Comment: Once this is done you're looking at probably around $250 parts and labor if you have a dealer replace the cylinder.  DIY, probably half that.

Comment: In this case wouldn't replacing the whole latch be easier cheaper? I mean from used I'm pretty sure this cost under 50$